# Javascript triggering the HTML form not to get data

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, forms

Hi I have a javascript that works like this :

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success"><b>Thank you! We will contact you as early as possible</b></p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });

    $( '#main-contact-form' ).each(function(){
        this.reset();
    });
});
```

And whenever I submit the form my aspx c# was not able to get the values of the form. But when I hardcoded the content in my aspx It works fine. Now I am not sure what in this line of code went something wrong. I tried removing the id of my html form "main-contact-form" and it works perfectly fine. therefore I think this is the part which I made mistake.
Can you help me ?

And if you will be asking for the mark up and my aspx content [here it is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294132/cannot-get-the-html-textbox-value)

Comment: You're not sending any data to the server: [settings -> data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: what do you mean I dont understand.. can you at least post your answer sir ? this is the farthest I could go for now, I am new to ajax..

Comment: Currently you're sending an request without any data (form input fields). You have to gather all the required data from the form and add it as the `data` property of the settings object you're passing to `$.ajax()` (the first link I've posted). You can simplify this task by using `.serialize()` (the second link).

Comment: sorry I dont follow ..can you show me instead ?

Comment: for the record I was able to send email using a hard coded input from aspx end on my c# code .. But whenever I did Request["nameOffieldinHTML"] It doesnt get it.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're using ASP.NET MVC or WebForms please?

Comment: I'm working on asp.net and using .Net.Mail sir